# How to show dataset on graph MPAndroidChart?

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I want to show the amount and date as month values on graph. For this I searched library [MPAndroid Chart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

But I am not getting how should I add data sets and convert date into month.

I want to show graph like this :

[image]

I have a Order object list which has amount and date.

I tried this code:

```
    totalOrdersList = new ArrayList<>();
        mChart = (BarChart) view.findViewById(R.id.chart);
       // mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(Dashboard2Fragment.this);
        // mChart.setHighlightEnabled(false);

        mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);

        mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
        mChart.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(),R.color.lightGrey));

        mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);

        // if more than 60 entries are displayed in the chart, no values will be
        // drawn
        mChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(60);

        // scaling can now only be done on x- and y-axis separately
        mChart.setPinchZoom(false);

        // draw shadows for each bar that show the maximum value
        // mChart.setDrawBarShadow(true);

        mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

        XAxis xl = mChart.getXAxis();
        xl.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xl.setDrawAxisLine(true);
        xl.setDrawGridLines(false);
        xl.setGranularity(10f);


        YAxis yl = mChart.getAxisLeft();
        yl.setDrawAxisLine(true);
        yl.setDrawGridLines(true);
        yl.setAxisMinimum(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)
//        yl.setInverted(true);

        YAxis yr = mChart.getAxisRight();
        yr.setDrawAxisLine(true);
        yr.setDrawGridLines(false);
        yr.setAxisMinimum(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)
//        yr.setInverted(true);

     //   setData();
        mChart.setFitBars(true);
        mChart.animateY(2500);


        Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
        l.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
        l.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
        l.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
        l.setDrawInside(false);
        l.setFormSize(8f);
        l.setXEntrySpace(4f);




     private void setData() {

        mChart.setScaleEnabled(false);

        int i=0;

        barEntries = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayList<String> amountArray = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> dateArray = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Order order : totalOrdersList)
        {

            amountArray.add(order.getAmount());
            dateArray.add(order.getDate());

        }

        for (String amount : amountArray)
        {
            barEntries.add(new BarEntry(1,Float.parseFloat(amount)));
        }

        BarDataSet completed = new BarDataSet(barEntries, "Amount");

        completed.setValues(barEntries);

        completed.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        completed.setValueTextSize(12f);

        Legend legend = new Legend();


        legend = mChart.getLegend();

        legend.setEnabled(true);

        mChart.setEnabled(false);
        mChart.setPinchZoom(false);

        mChart.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(false);
        mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
        mChart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);
        mChart.setHighlightPerDragEnabled(false);
        mChart.setDragDecelerationEnabled(false);


        XAxis xl = mChart.getXAxis();
        xl.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xl.setDrawAxisLine(true);
        xl.setDrawGridLines(false);
        xl.setDrawLabels(true);
        xl.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

        YAxis yl = mChart.getAxisLeft();
        yl.setDrawAxisLine(true);
        yl.setDrawGridLines(false);
        yl.setDrawLabels(true);


        YAxis yll = mChart.getAxisRight();
        yll.setDrawAxisLine(false);
        yll.setAxisLineColor(Color.WHITE);
        yll.setDrawGridLines(false);
        yll.setDrawLabels(false);

        ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>();
        dataSets.add(completed);

        BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);

        mChart.setData(data);

        mChart.invalidate();


    }
```

but getting graph like this:

[image]

What's going wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

You are setting all your `barEntries` to same index

```
for (String amount : amountArray)
    {
        barEntries.add(new BarEntry(1, Float.parseFloat(amount)));
    }
```

You need to change it as follows:

```
int index = 0;

for (String amount : amountArray)
    {
        barEntries.add(new BarEntry(index, Float.parseFloat(amount)));
        index++;
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Now to display date in your X-Axis, there is a great example mentioned in this [thread](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/789). You can create another `arrayList`of `long` to store your date in milliseconds.

```
private List<Long> timestampList = new ArrayList<>();

for (String dateString : dateArray) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMMM-dd");
            Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);

            long startDate = date.getTime();

            Log.d("timestamp:", String.valueOf(startDate));

            timestampList.add(startDate);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Now to display these milliseconds in month you have to use [IAxisValueFormatter](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-AxisValueFormatter-interface) interface to format your X-Axis values. You can use something like below to format your values:

```
 //Interface to get custom values for X-axis
    IAxisValueFormatter formatter = new IAxisValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestampList.get((int) value));
            int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            return new SimpleDateFormat("MMM").format(calendar.getTime());            }
    };
```

Finally to set values for X-Axis you can call

```
xl.setGranularity(1f); //So that the X-Axis values become 0, 1, 2, and so on...to query the timestampList() index
xl.setValueFormatter(formatter);
```

`getFormattedValue`will be called for every X-Axis value and then you can get the months accordingly.

Comment: how to add dates to x axis?? I am getting amount at x and y axis right now.

Comment: Use the IAxisValueFormatter as stated above

Comment: dates are not random vales they need to get from totalOrderList and show on x axis.

Comment: What are the values for date you are getting from totalOrderList?

Comment: {
            "amount": "5506.4300",
            "date_added": "2017-May-17th"
        },   values are in this format

Comment: can u please help me to make this graph??

Comment: Okay I finally managed to do it correctly, please check the edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152996/discussion-between-ayush-khare-and-sid).

Comment: You can have a look at the gist I posted in the chat discussion